# compare Excel value and get the row to nearest or same value from other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 02 worksheets, Worksheet one contain table where user will enter the data. Worksheet 2 contain all the data.
When user click on "Estimate" button then it should compare that value of Worksheet 1 with Worksheet 2 and provide the nearest/same value with entire row from worksheet 02.

I have attached 02 images,

[image]

and (2 -image contain the data worksheet 2)

[image]

(1 - images contain expected result and place where end user can enter the data)

```
Sub compare2()

Dim compId As Range
Range("I6").ClearContents
Set compId = Worksheets(2).Range("G11:G83").Find(what:=Worksheets(1).Range("c6").Value)

If Not compId Is Nothing Then
    Range("I6").Value = compId.Row()
Else
    MsgBox "Value does not match"
End If

End Sub
```

I tried above code but it does not provide the nearest/same value and does not provide the entire row

Comment: This range '.Range("G11:G83")' would appear to be nonsense in the context of your question.  Please update the images so that we know the row and column numbers.

Comment: @freeflow - that was the sample image, not the actual database. The existing database is more significant in size. Because of that, you see that range in my code.

Comment: It is not clear if you are looking for the nearest value row for an specific component "H2O"or you are looking for the row with the nearest values of all components. The code that you posted only searc for one specific component

Comment: Hello @wrbp
I am trying to search for the nearest/equal value in H2O and other columns and once it's found then it should provide the entire row of the lowest value. Suppose I entered 130 and click on an estimate then it found 130 in H2O column (worksheet 2) then, I should get an entire row of 130 (Like A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2). As shown in 2nd worksheet 1. Appreciate your help :) Thank you